# How to Convert CSV to JSON in Dataweave 2.0 in mulesoft without specific headers?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have CSV input file without headers

Input example are as follows

```
ETM, St. Petersburg
Date: 03/28/12
Number: 14.P3.11.12032818-1
Note:
LON 95w B-230-95-4 E27; 305003311; pcs; 30800; order; 322233.1; KP14278
DSh 60w DSh-230-60 E14; S0100325; pcs; 576; order; 322233.1; KP14278
DSh 40w DSh-230-40 E14; 321600316; pcs; 576; order ;; KP14278
LON 60w B-230-60-4 E27; 303456500; pcs; 16940; order ;; KP14278
```

The expected out should be in this JSON format

Basic Structure which is expected

```
{
  "orders": {
    "location": "",
    "deliveryDate": "",
    "orderNo": "",
    "Notes": ""
  },
  "ordersItems": {
    "itemsDetails": [
      {
        "materialdetails": "LON 95w B-230-95-4 E27",
        "referenceNo": "305003311",
        "uom": " pcs",
        "qty": " 30800",
        "docType": " order",
        "projectCode": " 322233.1",
        "description": " KP14278"
      },
      .....
      ...... 
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The input is not a CSV. Only the data below `Note:` could be considered a CSV.

Answer (score 3):

I concur with @aled, this does not look like a proper CSV file, but if you only want to parse the data starting from line 5 onwards you can do something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = "ETM, St. Petersburg
Date: 03/28/12
Number: 14.P3.11.12032818-1
Note:
LON 95w B-230-95-4 E27; 305003311; pcs; 30800; order; 322233.1; KP14278
DSh 60w DSh-230-60 E14; S0100325; pcs; 576; order; 322233.1; KP14278
DSh 40w DSh-230-40 E14; 321600316; pcs; 576; order ;; KP14278
LON 60w B-230-60-4 E27; 303456500; pcs; 16940; order ;; KP14278"

var fs = {
    column_0: "materialDetails",
    column_1: "referenceNo",
    column_2: "uom",
    column_3: "qty",
    column_4: "docType",
    column_5: "projectCode",
    column_6: "description"
}

var parsedRows = read(
    data, 
    "application/csv", 
    {separator: ";",header: false,bodyStartLineNumber: 5}
)

---
{
    orders: {
        location: "",
        deliveryDate: "",
        orderNo: "",
        Notes: ""
    },
    ordersItems: {
        itemsDetails: parsedRows map ($ mapObject {(fs[$$]): $})
    }
}
```

Note, I setup the data inside a string (primarily because I want my code self-contained) and the parsed using the `read()` function.  You can do something similar and skip the extra lines with your file.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I forgot the DataWeave bodyStartLineNumber reader property for CSV.

Comment: Thank you . Actually the CSV format is in russian language so i translated it through the translator so there might be mismatch of formats.I would also like to get the value of branch and date which is above the starting line number. I have a query like will it work for dynamic tons of records like fetching it from a file folder.?

Comment: ЭТМ,СПб
Дата:28.03.12
Номер:14.P3.11.12032818-1
Примечание:
ЛОН 95вт Б-230-95-4 Е27;305003311;шт;30800;заказ;322233.1;КП14278
ДШ 60вт ДШ-230-60 Е14;С0100325;шт;576;заказ;322233.1;КП14278
ДШ 40вт ДШ-230-40 Е14;321600316;шт;576;заказ;;КП14278
ЛОН 60вт Б-230-60-4 Е27;303456500;шт;16940;заказ;;КП14278

Comment: Modify the original post to contain the Russian input, and the exact output you need.